# QGraphicsView steals focus on hover on OSX?

Tags: qt

I have a QMainWindow with various QDockWidgets.  One of the QDockWidgets has a QDoubleSpinBox.  There's a QGraphicsView in the center.

When a user is editing a value in the SpinBox, and then hovers his mouse over the QGraphicsView, it steals the focus.  This is confirmed by checking QApplication::focusWidget() during the SpinBox's focusOutEvent()

Adding the following code eliminates the focus stealing, confirming that it is the case that the focus is travelling to the QGraphicsView.

```
void OtherQGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    QWidget *w = QApplication::focusWidget();
    if (w == this) {
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

As I understand it, Qt does not support the focus-follows-hover model.  How could the QGraphicsView gain focus just by a mouseMoveEvent?

Is there something I should be doing to the SpinBox to prevent the stealing from occurring?

For an example, **just load up the DiagramScene example from the Qt creator built-in examples**.  The font selector at the top will lose focus when the mouse hovers over the main panel.

edit: This happens on OSX (Yosemite) but not Windows (8.1)

edit 2:  Stack Trace when the offending event occurs:

```
0   NumberEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *)    inspector.cpp   123 0x10003cc00 
1   QWidget::event(QEvent *)    QWidget::event(QEvent*)     0x1001a8add 
2   QAbstractSpinBox::event(QEvent *)   QAbstractSpinBox::event(QEvent*)        0x100252bc9 
3   QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *) QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)       0x10016932b 
4   QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)   QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x10016c648 
5   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject *, QEvent *)   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x100fe1d83 
6   QApplicationPrivate::setFocusWidget(QWidget *, Qt::FocusReason) QApplicationPrivate::setFocusWidget(QWidget*, Qt::FocusReason)      0x1001670ce 
7   QWidget::setFocus(Qt::FocusReason)  QWidget::setFocus(Qt::FocusReason)      0x1001a4809 
8   QApplicationPrivate::giveFocusAccordingToFocusPolicy(QWidget *, QEvent *, QPoint)   QApplicationPrivate::giveFocusAccordingToFocusPolicy(QWidget*, QEvent*, QPoint)     0x10016d348 
9   QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)   QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x10016bef1 
10  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject *, QEvent *)   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x100fe1d83 
11  QApplicationPrivate::translateRawTouchEvent(QWidget *, QTouchDevice *, QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> const&, unsigned long)    QApplicationPrivate::translateRawTouchEvent(QWidget*, QTouchDevice*, QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> const&, unsigned long)      0x10016ef2b 
12  QWidgetWindow::event(QEvent *)  QWidgetWindow::event(QEvent*)       0x1001c2eb5 
13  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject *, QEvent *) QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)       0x10016932b 
14  QApplication::notify(QObject *, QEvent *)   QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x10016c648 
15  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject *, QEvent *)   QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)     0x100fe1d83 
16  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processTouchEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::TouchEvent *)  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processTouchEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::TouchEvent*)       0x10081eb09 
17  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent *)    QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*)     0x10081bc69 
18  QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)   QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)       0x1008092da 
19  QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void *)    QCocoaEventDispatcherPrivate::postedEventsSourceCallback(void*)     0x1033b0411 
20  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__      0x7fff895e87c1  
21  __CFRunLoopDoSources0   __CFRunLoopDoSources0       0x7fff895da94d  
22  __CFRunLoopRun  __CFRunLoopRun      0x7fff895d9f7f  
23  CFRunLoopRunSpecific    CFRunLoopRunSpecific        0x7fff895d9998  
24  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode       0x7fff880a27df  
25  ReceiveNextEventCommon  ReceiveNextEventCommon      0x7fff880a245e  
26  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter    _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter        0x7fff880a239b  
27  _DPSNextEvent   _DPSNextEvent       0x7fff8b739a6d  
28  -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]    -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]        0x7fff8b739220  
29  -[NSApplication run]    -[NSApplication run]        0x7fff8b72d0c3  
30  QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) QCocoaEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)     0x1033af2fd 
31  QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)     0x100fdf37d 
32  QCoreApplication::exec()    QCoreApplication::exec()        0x100fe235a 
33  main    main.cpp    100 0x100004b82 
34  start   start       0x100004014
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug.I'd report it a such in the Qt bugtracker, with a minimal example

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem with some minimal code? This would prove that it is not caused by some code of yours which you didn't think of. Does `QGraphicsScene` contains some focusable item?

Comment: put a break point in this method and reproduce problem. When program will stop check call stack if it doesn't contains anything disturbing. Paste this call stack to your question.

Comment: The only thing in the stack trace that's odd is QGuiApplicationPrivate::processTouchEvent

Comment: QWindow::touchEvent() is never called, and the focus widget's Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents is false.

Comment: The built-in example Diagram Scene Example exhibits this behaviour.  The font and font size selectors will lose focus when the mouse enters the main panel.

Comment: I have entered a bug with Qt: [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46351)